# What's the difference between a 'function', 'method' and 'bound method' in Python 3?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, python-internals

I've observed at least 3 types related to functions in Python 3:

```
>>> class A():
...  def f(): pass
...
>>> A.f
<function A.f at 0x7fcaef304268>
>>> A().f
<bound method A.f of <__main__.A object at 0x7fcaef2fae80  
>>> set.union
<method 'union' of 'set' objects>
```

I'm wondering what's the difference between 'function', 'method' and 'bound method'? Is 'method' a type equivalent to 'unbound method' in Python 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is 'method' a type equivalent to 'unbound method' in Python 2?

Kind-a-sort-a. But not really. It is a `method_descriptor` object defined in C code. It is an unbound method, but not the kind you found in Python 2.

For Python types written C, all 'methods' are really C functions. The `<method 'name' of 'type' objects>` object you found is a special object you can use to call that function given an instance and further arguments, just like the `function` object does for custom Python classes. The object is defined in C in the [`PyMethodDescr_Type` structure](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/descrobject.c#l493). It implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), just like functions do.

Python defines several other such descriptor types; if you use [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots), each attribute is a dsescriptor of type `member_descriptor` (see the [`PyMemberDescr_Type` structure](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/descrobject.c#l568)), while `classmethod`, `property` and `staticmethod` are perhaps better known descriptor objects.

In Python 2, bound and unbound methods are really just *one* type, `instancemethod` (defined by the [`PyMethod_Type` structure](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/classobject.c#l2633)); it'll report as bound if the `__self__` (`im_self`) attribute is set. In Python 3 using a function as a descriptor simply doesn't produce method objects without `__self__` set; instead calling `function.__get__()` with no instance just returns the function again.

The only reason Python 2 returns unbound methods is to *enforce a type check*; the first argument must be an instance of the class (or a subclass thereof). This didn't make all that much sense for Python code that supports duck-typing, so in Python 3 the restriction was removed. However, with C code you can't use duck-typing, you still have to restrict the type, and that's why *C-types* still return a `method_descriptor` object that enforces this restriction.