# Python - function as class attribute becomes a bound method

Tags: python, methods, class-attributes

I noticed that if I define a class attribute equal to a function when I create an instance of that class the attribute becomes a bound method. Can someone explain me the reason of this behaviour?

```
In [9]: def func():
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [10]: class A(object):
   ....:     f = func
   ....:     

In [11]: a = A()

In [12]: a.f
Out[12]: <bound method A.func of <__main__.A object at 0x104add190>>

In [13]: a.f()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-19134f1ad9a8> in <module>()
----> 1 a.f()
    global a.f = <bound method A.func of <__main__.A object at 0x104add190>>

TypeError: func() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You assigned a function to the attribute `A.f` (the attribute `f` of the class `A`). The attribute `A.f` was defined as part of the class. It is a function, so it is by default an *instance method* of that class.

Creating an instance (named `a`) of class `A` causes that instance to have an attribute `f`, and you access that by the name `a.f`. This is a bound method (cause it's bounded to the object `a`; [further explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35174759/whats-the-difference-between-a-function-method-and-bound-method-in-pytho)).

Every instance method, when it is called, automatically receives the instance as its first argument (conventionally named `self`). Other types of method are possible: - see [class methods and static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179271/python-classmethod-and-staticmethod-for-beginner).

For this reason the error says that `func` takes no arguments (as it's defined as `def func():`) but received 1 (`self`).

To do what you want, you should tell python that you're using a [static method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod)

```
def func():
    pass

class A(object):
    f = staticmethod(func)
```

Answer (score 2):

Python is *not* a message based OO system<sup>1</sup>. Instead, similar to JavaScript, properties are resolved to first-class functions and then invoked; the behavior differs a bit in the mechanics of such, as discovered.

In Python the requirement is that methods have at least one parameter, normally called `self`, that will be automatically supplied the associated instance *when* it is invoked as a method.

Furthermore (and perhaps to the point of the question), Python does not differentiate between using `def f..` or `f = some_func()` when establishing instance member bindings; arguably this matches behavior outside of classes.

In the example, assigning the function to the instance 'makes it expect to be treated like an instance method'. It is the exact same - parameterless - function called in both cases; only the future usage of such is relevant.

Now, unlike JavaScript, Python handles methods and object association through the concept of bound methods - functions resolved as methods are always 'bound'.

The behavior of `a.f` returning a bound method - function that will automatically supply the bound object to the first parameter as `self` - is done independently of the source of the function. In this case that means the parameterless function cannot be used when it is 'bound' as it does not accept a `self` parameter.

As a demonstration, the following will fail in the same way because the source underlying method does *not* meet the minimum requirements of accepting the instance as an argument:

```
g = a.f
g()
```

In this case calling `g()` is equivalent to calling `func(a)`.

---

<sup>1</sup> For comparison, Java, C#, Ruby, and SmallTalk are message based OO systems - in these an object is told to invoke a method by a 'name', instead of resolving a method (or function) as a value which can be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but another viable solution is in storing the function as dictionary, which is an attribute of the class.

```py
# Some arbitrary function
def f(x):
  return x

# A class, which will wrap the function as a dictionary object, which is a class attr
class Test:
  def __init__(self,f):
    self.f = {'f':f}
  
  def func(self,x):
    return self.f['f'](x)

# Now let's test the Test object
t = Test(f=f)
t.func(3)

>>>
3
```

This approach is more verbose than the accepted answer, however, it doesn't get into staticmethod, decorators, or other advanced topics. So, this will work in a pinch if you're intimidated by the other, preferred approach.

Edit: If you want this to robust enough to handle keyword arguments:

```py
class Test:
  def __init__(self,f):
    self.f = {'f':f}
  
  def func(self,p):
    return self.f['f'](**p)

def f(**p):
  return p['x'] * p['y']

t = Test(f=f)
t.func({'x':2,'y':3})

>>>
6
```