# Python: Why do functools.partial functions not become bound methods when set as class attributes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, functools

I was reading about how [functions become bound methods when being set as class atrributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35321744/python-function-as-class-attribute-becomes-a-bound-method). I then observed that this is not the case for functions that are wrapped by `functools.partial`. What is the explanation for this?

Simple example:

```py
from functools import partial

def func1():
    print("foo")

func1_partial = partial(func1)

class A:
    f = func1
    g = func1_partial

a = A()


a.f() # TypeError: func1() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

a.g() # prints "foo"
```

I kind of expected them both to behave in the same way.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/functools.py#L275) in the source code tells the reason: *Purely functional, no "**descriptor**" behaviour*. `partial` is a class not a function. Functions are descriptors they provide `__get__`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trick that allows functions to become bound methods is the [`__get__` magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

To *very* briefly summarize that page, when you access a field on an instance, say `foo.bar`, Python first checks whether `bar` exists in `foo`'s `__dict__` (or `__slots__`, if it has one). If it does, we return it, no harm done. If not, then we look on `type(foo)`. *However,* when we access the field `Foo.bar` on the *class* `Foo` through an instance, something magical happens. When we write `foo.bar`, assuming there is no `bar` on `foo`'s `__dict__` (resp. `__slots__`), then we actually call `Foo.bar.__get__(foo, Foo)`. That is, Python calls a magic method asking the object how it would like to be retrieved.

This is how [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) are implemented, and it's also how bound methods are implemented. Somewhere deep down (probably written in C), there's a `__get__` function on the *type* `function` that binds the method when accessed through an instance.

`functools.partial`, despite looking a lot like a function, is not an instance of the type `function`. It's just a random class that happens to implement `__call__`, and it doesn't implement `__get__`. Why doesn't it? Well, they probably just didn't think it was worth it, or it's possible nobody even considered it. Regardless, the "bound method" trick applies to the type called `function`, not to all callable objects.

---

Another useful resource on magic methods, and `__get__` in particular: https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/#descriptor

Comment: Note that `Foo.bar` is "magical", too. The `__get__` method is still invoked, but it simply returns the function itself, rather than a new instance of `method`.

Comment: Txs for making the class  w `__call__` vs function object distinction.  That explains much of the rest.

Answer (score 5):

The type `function` implements the `__get__` method:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.FunctionType.__get__
<slot wrapper '__get__' of 'function' objects>
```

`partial` does not.

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> partial.__get__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'functools.partial' has no attribute '__get__'. Did you mean: '__ge__'?
```

The `__get__` method is what makes `a.f` evaluate to a value of type `method` instead of `A.f`. Without `__get__`, `a.g` is equivalent to `A.g`.